# The bootstrap modal blacked out because updating a $scope variable.

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

The Java Script code

```
$scope.popAccept = function(){




$http({
        method : 'POST',
        url : "/MobileAPP/getAcceptance",
        data : {"acceptedInvoice":$scope.acceptedInvoice},
        headers : {'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).success(
            function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                if (response == "FAILURE") {
                    $
                            .snackbar({
                                content : "Request Submission Failed. Please contact support",                                          
                                timeout : 10000
                            });
                } else {

                    var index  = $scope.details.indexOf($scope.acceptedInvoice); 
                    $scope.details.splice(index,1); 


                    $.snackbar({
                        content : "Request Submitted Successfully",
                        style : "toast",
                        timeout : 10000
                    }); 

                    }

            });

}
```

The HTML Code

```
      <button id="modbutton" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" ng-click="popAccept()" data-dismiss="modal">Accept</button>
```

When the $scope.details is not updated, the modal is closing. If i update the $scope.details, the modal disappears and the blacked out screen appears. Does splice method or updating of the $scope.details is effecting the modal state.  Please Help me out on this.